# How to create a data frame from different Text files

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operating-system

I was working on a project where I have to scrape the some text files from a source. I completed this task and I have 140 text file.

[image: Sample Text File]
This is one of the text file I have scraped.

I am trying to create a dataframe where I should have one row for each text file. So I wrote the below code:-

```
import pandas as pd
import os

txtfolder = r'/home/spx072/Black_coffer_assignment/' #Change to your folder path

#Find the textfiles
textfiles = []
for root, folder, files in os.walk(txtfolder):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith('.txt'):
            fullname = os.path.join(root, file)
            textfiles.append(fullname)
# textfiles.sort() #Sort the filesnames

#Read each of them to a dataframe
for filenum, file in enumerate(textfiles, 1):
    if filenum==1:
        df = pd.read_csv(file, names=['data'], sep='delimiter', header=None)
        df['Samplename']=os.path.basename(file)
    else:
        tempdf = pd.read_csv(file,  names=['data'], sep='delimiter', header=None)
        tempdf['Samplename']=os.path.basename(file)
        df = pd.concat([df, tempdf], ignore_index=True)
        
df = df[['Samplename','data']] #
```

The code runs fine, but the dataframe I am getting is some thing like this :-

[image: Sample Dataframe]

I want that each text file should be inside a single row like:-

1.txt should be in df['data'][0],
2.txt should be in df['data'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgwkB.png) and so on.

I tried different codes and also check several questions but still unable to get the desired result. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not shure why you need pd.read_csv() for this. Try it with pure python:

```
result = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Samplename', 'data'])
for file in textfiles:
    with open(file) as f:
        data = f.read()
    result = pd.concat([result, pd.DataFrame({'Samplename' : file, 'data': data}, index=[0])], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but could you please confirm from where you are taking this content variable, as I am getting error:-NameError: name 'content' is not defined

Comment: Let me change it to the naming convention you are using.

Comment: You don't need the filenum in this example, so you can omit the enumerate() function also.

Comment: Thank you so much, it finally fixed what I was looking for. Fixed